# openpyxl cannot append list data type, keep showing TypeError: Value must be a list

Tags: python, openpyxl

Here is my code

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def get_data_list(filename, sheetname):
    data = record = []
    # load excel file, read only mode
    wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
    # select sheet
    sheet = wb[sheetname]

    # write into data
    for row in sheet.rows:
        for cell in row:
            record.append(cell.value)
        data.append(record)
        record = []
    return data 

def write_data_list(data, filename, sheetname, no_header=False):
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    sheet.title = sheetname

    # check header data
    if no_header :
        data.pop(0)

    # insert data
    for row in data:
        sheet.append(row)

    # save into file
    wb.save(filename)

data = get_data_list('excel/sample.xlsx','Sheet1')
# print(type(data))
write_data_list(data, 'data.xlsx', 'data')
```

I run this code and produce this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Projects\mergexl\rw.py", line 37, in <module>
    write_data_list(data, 'data.xlsx', 'data')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Projects\mergexl\rw.py", line 31, in write_data_list
    sheet.append(row)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.virtualenvs\mergexl-aotJkH4X\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 788, in append
    self._invalid_row(iterable)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.virtualenvs\mergexl-aotJkH4X\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 872, in _invalid_row
    type(iterable))
TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>
```

As you see, this error shows a problem on line 33, which **"sheet.append(row)"** keep asking list data type input. But, the variable *data* is already a list. I have checked *data* type by

```
print(type(data))
```

then the output is **class 'list'**
but the error message keep telling that *data* is **class 'str'**

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = record = []` isn't doing what you think it does.

It binds `data` and `record` names to the same list object.

The first time the following loop runs, `data` and `record` are the same list and all in `cell.value` in the first row are added to that list before `record` is added.

`cell.value` are not instances of the list class.

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row:
        record.append(cell.value)
    data.append(record)
    record = []
return data
```

You need to initialize data and record as separate lists.

```
data = []

for row in sheet.rows:
    record = []
    for cell in row:
        record.append(cell.value)
    data.append(record)

return data
```